# C# cannot resolve OnClickListener to can't resolve symbol view

Tags: java, android-studio

First there was an error I can't resolve onclicklistener and now this view can not be resolved error!

Here is what I'm coding. What's the problem at (View view)?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText UserName;
    private EditText Password;
    private Button Login;
    private TextView CopyRights;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        UserName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LogUsername);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LoginPasswprd);
        Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.LoginButton);
        CopyRights = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.LoginAppInfo);

        Login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener){

                    public void OnClick(View view){


            }
        });
    }


    private void validate(String name, String pass){

        if( (name.isEmpty() ) || (pass.isEmpty() )){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ErrActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else if( ( name == "Admin") || (pass == "12345")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AdmActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail about what you are trying to accomplish?  At what point do you receive the error?

Comment: i was creating a sign in page and then when i tried to set up validation and all the onsetclicklistener created the problem and since then